# Kernel dynamic debug output

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04, printk

I'm trying to see log messages that are written with `dev_err()` function in a kernel module, I tried `sudo dmesg -n 7` and `echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk`
None of them started to print `dev_err` messages to `dmesg`.

I also noticed that dev_err function is empty in the kernel source:

> include/linux/device.h

```
void dev_err(const struct device *dev, const char *fmt, ...)
{}
```

I've also tried `echo -n 'module <module name> +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control` (`debugfs` is mounted and `dynamic_debug/control` exists), for some reason, when I `cat` `dynamic_debug/control` and `grep` the module name I don't see it in there, I think this is the main problem, for example:

```
$ echo -n "file include/net/bluetooth/hci_core.h +p" > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

this command doesn't add `include/net/bluetooth/hci_core.h` to `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`

why?

(I'm using ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, kernel 4.8.0-36-generic)

How can I print `dev_err` log messages to `dmesg`?
Thanks.

Comment: It's only empty if `CONFIG_PRINTK` is undefined. It is defined by default.

Comment: `CONFIG_PRINTK=y` on my build

Comment: in linux source it is also empty `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/device.h`

Comment: I don't know why you are getting nothing in `dmesg` if you built with `CONFIG_PRINTK=y`. It should be using the definition of `dev_err` in "drivers/core.c" in that case. (Note that the `dev_err` function is defined by the macro call `define_dev_printk_level(dev_err, KERN_ERR);` in "drivers/core.c" if `CONFIG_PRINTK` is defined. The inline definition in "include/linux/device.h" is only used if `CONFIG_PRINTK` is not defined.)

Comment: You could at least try bisecting the problem.  Use the `strings` command on the kernel module binary to see if the text of the messages are embedded.  Or review the output of the preprocessor.